# Serve wordpress blog from subdirectory with django and wsgi

Tags: django, wordpress, wsgi

I'm currently on shared hosting plan with dreamhost and have installed Django as per http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django . However, I also have a wordpress blog that I wish to keep running in a subdirectory, i.e, site.com/blog.

Is it possible to do this. Installing Django results in a passenger_wsgi.py file in the Django root directory which redirects all the requests to django

if i try to go to my blog i get an error since obviously it's not in url.py. Is it possible to somehow serve the wordpress blog as is by configuring wsgi or django, and how can i do this?

Thanks for your time

P.S. I currently have renamed passenger_wsgi.py so that the blog shows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable Phusion Passenger for specific locations in the Passenger app using the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.com
    DocumentRoot /apps/foo/public
    <Directory /apps/foo/public/wordpress>
        PassengerEnabled off
        AllowOverride all      # <-- Makes Wordpress's .htaccess file work.
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For more tricks, check out the Phusion Passenger [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt)

Comment: Oh great, seems like what i'm looking for!

Comment: Where would i place the override since i don't have access to the apache config file?

Comment: Check your control panel for options, or it might be hidden in your user directory, as some hosts do. If you have command line access try # find / -name 'httpd.conf' -print You may have to contact your hosting provider instead. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

For those who is on shared hosting you can create file `.htaccess` under `/path/to/your/blog` with one line in it:

```
PassengerEnabled off
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you parxier, this was a perfectly simple solution to my own Wordpress on Django on Dreamhost question!