# How to use Wordpress and Django together

Tags: django, wordpress, configuration, blogs

I host my Django site [Wantbox.com](http://wantbox.com) on Dreamhost. I'd like to use Wordpress for the Wantbox blog and locate it here: http://wantbox.com/blog/

How do I configure Django to lay off "/blog/" so Wordpress can do it's thing? Right now, I have a catch-all url pattern which sends anything not specified to the homepage and this catch-all is catching "/blog/" and doing just that.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**
It's not necessary for Django data to be accessible by Wordpress or vica-versa. Also, I'm open to a Django-based blog solution, if it works as well as the tried-and-true Wordpress that I'm quite familiar with.

Comment: I'll move my answer up here: this is more of a webserver configuration question.  Assuming you're on Apache, can you post your Apache configuration?

Comment: Dreamhost uses Passenger WSGI for Django deployment. I have access to that config file only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found via Google a similar SO question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061388/serve-wordpress-blog-from-subdirectory-with-django-and-wsgi). The answer is to create an .htaccess file in the root of your new blog folder. In my case, the blog root directory is here: ~/wantbox.com/public/blog/

My **.htaccess** file in this directory has one line:

```
PassengerEnabled off
```

Now the url pattern http://wantbox.com/blog/ is ignored by Django and handled by Wordpress. Very nice.